# how to handle null exception using dynamic query execute in bulk collect?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My code is :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LV_SEARCH_QUERY bulk collect into  p_search;
```

`p_search` is collection.

`LV_search` is dynamic query string variable.

if i'm executing ,  null value has return from this query. how to handle the below error.

> Error report - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at
>   line 21
>   06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>   *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>              occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>              assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>              attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>              declared NUMBER(2).
>   *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>              that values do not violate constraints.

how to get exception in collection  & bulk collect or how to handle it?

Comment: Please post the p_search declaration

Answer (score 0):

In such case when we do not use collection, Oracle provides us `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception to handle if we have no rows returns from the query. But when we use collection, `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception will not handled. We can do a work around as below.

Once you execute your statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LV_SEARCH_QUERY bulk collect into  p_search;
```

Do a check like:

```
 IF p_search.count = 0 THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('No Records in the Test Table');
 END IF;
```

The above will show that your collection is empty.

----**Elaborative Example:**-----

As mentioned in my comment you are getting error not becuase you have `NULL` being returned from the `execute immediate` statement. It is because you are trying to insert a `non-numeric` character in a type declare to hold `numeric` or any case like that.

**Example1:** To check if the collect has data or not

Table created with column as `NUMBER` datatype

```
SQL> desc test2;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NUM                                                NUMBER

SQL> select * from test2;

no rows selected
```

Block to handle `NULL` in collection

```
 SQL> set serverout on
    SQL> DECLARE
       TYPE var IS TABLE OF NUMBER
          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

       v_var   var;

       v_sql   VARCHAR2 (100);
    BEGIN
       v_sql := 'Select num from test2';

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_var;

       IF v_var.COUNT = 0
       THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No Records in the Test Table');
       END IF;
    END;  
    /
    No Records in the Test Table

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
 SQL>
```

**Example 2:** When you try to insert a non-numeric character to a type declared to handle numeric character. You are getting this issue. You can see here that i used an exception block to handle such issue. So even though the exception is raised, the procedure is successfully comepleted.

```
 SQL> desc test2;
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     COL1                                               VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)

 SQL> select * from test2;

    COL1
    ----------
    XXX
    YYYW

  SQL> DECLARE
   TYPE var IS TABLE OF INTEGER
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   v_var   var;

   v_sql   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   v_sql := 'Select col1 from test2';

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO v_var;

   IF v_var.COUNT = 0
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No Records in the Test Table');
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;   
/
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 11

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: hi xing. i tried it, but its not working. prblem is- when im executing the bulkcollect line, it return null value then i faced error, when i posted it.

Comment: Yes bt the error has nothing to do with No_data_found handling. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error string

 Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable declared NUMBER(2).

Comment: @SabarishMahalingam thats is what i explained in my answer, Error shows that you are assign non-numeric values to numeric field.

Comment: actually im executing Null record query through execute command, so the error was shown in that time. my question is how to handle it in exception or any other way to solve this error?

Comment: @SabarishMahalingam . I guess you are not understanding what error you are getting. The error you get has nothing to do with null from execute immediate statement. See my elaborative example.

Comment: i understood your justification sir.. i'm giving wrong input to my proc knowingly to check my validation and exception things. let me check with this code.. thank you